# Deleting multiple occurrences of a string in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following strings in an error log:

```
> [Mon Mar 17 20:14:34 2014] [error] [client 71.79.132.230] File does not exist: /home/dom/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.dom.com/
  [Mon Mar 17 20:14:47 2014] [error] [client 68.62.210.110] File does not exist: /home/dom/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.dom.com/
  [Mon Mar 17 20:15:05 2014] [error] [client 68.230.61.226] File does not exist: /home/dom/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.dom.com/
```

I want to be able to sort them so that I only have one report of `/home/dom/public_html/404.shtml`, but the strings are not technically duplicates because the client IPs are not the same. I used `notepad++` textfx function but I don't see how to sort based only on the `/home/dom/public_html/404.shtml` string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is rather specific, because most people use scripts or other programs to evaluate logfiles. I know nothing about the textfx function or plugin (?) and what you do with it. Are you familiar with any programming language?

Answer (score 0):

If you have (or you can adjust) all the left parts of log entries (`[Mon Mar 17 20:14:34 2014] [error] [client 71.79.132.230]` ) of the **same length**, here is an ***unique sort*** functionality you are searching for:

1. ensure that menu item `TextFX` > `TextFX Tools` > `+Sort outputs only UNIQUE (at column)` is checked (if not, select it so it becomes checked)
2. create column selection which includes all the right parts of log entries (<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+Drag or <kbd>Letf Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>)
3. select menu item `TextFX` > `TextFX Tools` > `+Sort lines case sensitive (at column)`